# web service and DataContractJsonSerializer : dealing with dictionary

Tags: web-services, dictionary, serialization, json.net, datacontractserializer

I'm building a web service on iis + asp.net and I'm stuck with a problem about JSON serialization.
When using JSON.Net or JavaScriptSerializer, a dictionary is serialized as

```
{
 'key0':'value0',
 ...
 'keyN':'valueN',
}
```

but when it goes through the "ASP deserializer", a dictionary is serialized like this

```
[
 {Key:'key0',Value:'value0'},
 ...
 {Key:'keyN',Value:'valueN'}
]
```

I'm not familiar with ASP.net web services so I'm using a readymade template for visual studio.
WHen I look in the web.config I see there are defintions for endpoints and behaviours. In one of those behaviour I see there's a reference to dataContractSerializer.
This seems to be the serializer that is used under the hood when deserializing.

So my questions are :

- **Does dataContractSerializer can be tweaked to serialize the sane way
  (by using a directive in the web config) ?**
- **Can I set another Serializer (JSON.net ?) for the endpoint in the
  web.config ?**

My method currently outputs a Dictionary I change it to return a string (which I feed with my own serialization of my dictionary). But this didn't help much because the string get escaped by the default serializer that encloses it with '"'.

**Can I override this ? By writing directly to the Response and ending the response ?**

Please help me, I -really- don't want to change the existing client so I need to do it server side.

Comment: What specific web services framework and version are you using?  [tag:wcf]?  [tag:asp.net-web-api2]?  Something else?

Comment: The .net framework version is 4.5. I don't which ws framework is used : it's a template. Its ProjectTypeGuids is 349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21 so it is either "Model-View-Controller v5 (MVC 5)" or "Web Application". It does not look like a MVC because there's no model/views dir. It's a rather straihgtforward architecture : an IService.cs wich defines a [ServiceContract] and the implementation of this in Service.svc

Comment: The plumbing is started in the global.asax with a RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("REST", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ServiceREST)));

Comment: In .NET Framework 4.5 and later `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` has a `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` property which will cause the serializer to write the key-value pairs in the way you want.  I don't know whether you can set this via the configuration file (I doubt it), but if you can change the code where the `DataContractJsonSerializer` is created, that should fix your issue.

Comment: That's the problem. All of this is done in "automated" way so there's little I can do about it. But following links about your suggestion of using "UseSimpleDictionaryFormat" property, I found some references for a complete replacement of by json.net : https://jeroenhildering.com/2014/03/21/replacing-wcf-datacontractjsonserializer-with-newtonsoft-jsonserializer/ I'll give it a try. thank you.